# Finding Subsets of $A$ that involves $a$ and $b$, not involves $f$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A =\{a,b,c,e,d,f\} $$

- How do we find the subsets of $A$ that involves $a$ and $b$, not involves $f$?

I know that

$$\text {S} = 2^n$$

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Think of all the subsets $B=\{c, d, e \}$.

Then union each with $\{a, b\}$.

Comment: Could you be more clear? So, should we think that $2^4 = 16$?

Comment: Yes, that would be the number of subsets. The way I wrote it also tells you what those subsets are.

Comment: but it seems like $8$?

Comment: Edited. Sorry, yes. 8.